# adding a not contain to a if and a when statement

Tags: xslt

I have a form that has block 1 and block 2 and I want to filter out anyone that does not contain 3 letters example ABC.  Currently, I have an if statement that checks for a true status and I want to add a does not contain ABC to it.  I also want to add it to the when statement.

Example of if:

```
<xsl:if test="(($RegEmployee = 'true') or ($ExecEmployee = 'true'))">
```

Example of when:

```
<xsl:variable name="block2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($RegEmployee = 'true') or ($ExecEmployee = 'true')">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

I need to check if it has ABC in a variable named custonBonusSegName and if it does then make it false.  My variable is checking the following.

```
<xsl:variable name="customBonusSegName" select="./vp-total-payout- 
report[@formTemplateId='397']/vp-custom-data/vp-custom-field[@id='customBonusSegName']"/>
```

I would like to have a statement similar to the one I already use but instead of contains I want not contains.

```
<xsl:variable name="BonusSubtitle">
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="contains($customBonusSegName,'ABC')">
<xsl:value-of select="'False'"/>

</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="'True'"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Please read: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
test="($RegEmployee = 'true' or $ExecEmployee = 'true') and not(contains($customBonusSegName, 'ABC'))"
```

Untested, because no code to test with was provided.

---

P.S. Note that a construct like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="($RegEmployee = 'true') or ($ExecEmployee = 'true')">
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise> 
        <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

can be expressed simply as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$RegEmployee = 'true' or $ExecEmployee = 'true'" />
```